# Oracle - Need advice on multiple counts, on table with large amounts of data

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, plsql

Table with large data, does anyone know how to optimize the count statement?

Eg: table Booking(id, email, mobile,....) (about 30 fields).

```
Function GetBookingCount(p_email, p_mobile) return number
    Select count(id) 
    from Booking 
    Where email = p_email 
    or mobile = p_mobile

Function GetBookingStatus3Count(p_email, p_mobile) return number
    Select count(id) 
    from Booking
    Where (email = p_email or mobile = p_mobile) 
    and status = 3;
```

Final select:

```
Select GetBookingCount(email, mobile) as BookingCount
      , GetBookingStatus3Count(email, mobile) as BookingStatus3Count
      , ...
From Booking
where ....
```

solution1: Set the field column index what in where clause to count as email column, mobile, status column.

solution2: create a new table with few columns to count.
new table: Booking_Stats(id, email, mobile, status).

Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(*) count_all, count( case when status=3 then 1 else null end ) count_status_3
from Booking
where email = p_email and mobile = p_mobile
```

//NOTE: Query is written from head, not tested

You would consider creating an index on (email,mobile) or on (email,mobile,status) depending how many lines for given (email,mobile) you get and would you pay the cost of update of the index for status change (if allowed). In case of many updates of status for the same line, you might prefer indexing only (email,mobile) [read/write cost trade off].

Email is likely very discriminant (one value filters out most of the columns). If that is not the case, consider changing order to (mobile,email) if mobile column is better candidate.

Comment: Thanks you for detailed knowledge, but your sql also same my solution 1

Comment: @hungudgm Ok, I didn't deduce it from question. That would be the best way in your situation.

Answer (score 1):

It seems likely all those `GetBookingBlahBlah()` functions are not helpful and in fact quiet injurious to performance.

You haven't posted a complete set of requirements (what is meant by `...`?), so it's difficult to be certain, but it seems likely that a solution along these lines would be more performative:

```
with bk as (
    select *
    from booking 
    where email = p_email 
    or mobile = p_mobile
)
select count(*) as BookingCount
       , count(case when bk.status = 3 then 1 end) as BookingStatus3Count
       , ...
from bk
```

The idea is to query the base table **once**, getting all the data necessary to calculate all the counts, and crunching the aggregates on the smallest result set possible.

An index on `booking(email,mobile)` might be useful but probably not. A better solution would be to have different queries for each of `p_email` and `p_mobile`, with single column indexes supporting each query.

Answer (score 0):

The booking table should have an index on email, mobile and status. You should use this select:

```
    WITH B1 AS
(
     SELECT ID,
            COUNT(ID) CNT1,
            STATUS
     FROM BOOKING
     WHERE EMAIL = P_EMAIL
           AND MOBILE = P_MOBILE
)
SELECT CNT1,
       COUNT(ID) CNT2
FROM B1
WHERE STATUS = 3;
```

Comment: Thanks, but your sql maybe wrong, not working, please see sql in oracle